# writing files, reading them and call them with different moduls

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to save variables after I run a program to a text file and read them in different module, to call them back in the original program. Point of that is to write plots with 4 different outcome of the main program.

attempt at coding

```
#main program

a = array([[0.05562032, 0.05386903, 0.05216994, 0.03045489, 0.03029977,
        0.03014554],
       [0.        , 0.00175129, 0.00345037, 0.15353227, 0.1536874 ,
        0.15384163]])
#save paramaters in external file
save_paramaters = open('save.txt','w')
save_paramaters.write(str(a))
save_paramaters.close()
```

I open the txt file in  python module and save it as a variable, which I corrected manually(replacing spaces with commas)

```
#new program

dat = "save.txt"
b = open(dat, "r")
c = array(b.read())
```

In the main program I now call the variable with

```
a = array([[0.05562032, 0.05386903, 0.05216994, 0.03045489, 0.03029977,
        0.03014554],
       [0.        , 0.00175129, 0.00345037, 0.15353227, 0.1536874 ,
        0.15384163])
#save paramaters in external file
save_paramaters = open('save.txt','w')
save_paramaters.write(str(a))
save_paramaters.close()

#open the variable
from program import c
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, plot
#and try to plot it
plot(c[1][:], label ='results2')
plot(c[0][:], label ='results1')





  File "/Example.py", line 606, in example
      plot(c[1][:], label ='results2')   #model

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace please, its much easier to diagnose an error if you know what line it occurred on.

Comment: Added but this is an example, so idk if that would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save an array you can't just save it as text and expect python to figure it out. When you read it, you're reading it as text (as a string) and that's all your program can know.

If you want to save complex objects you have several other options:

1. You can save text (as you do) but parse it manually when reading it to turn it into an array. This is complex to write without bugs and will get even more complex if you have anything even more complex than an array.
2. You can save it using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) - while this is a good solution for almost all objects, the file created wouldn't be readable to humans, and that's perhaps not what you want.
3. A good middle ground is to save objects as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) - this is a standard for most datatypes and would work beautifully for dicts and lists and tuples (but will fail with more complex objects), and more importantly, it will be readable to humans such as yourself.

Let's say you go with JSON. You save a list like this:

```
import json
with open('save.txt','w') as f:
    json.dump(your_object, f)
```

As simple as that. To read back the list:

```
import json
with open('save.txt','r') as f:
    your_new_object = json.load(f)
```

This is fairly simple isn't it? Notice I used a `with` statement to open the files to make sure they close properly as well, but that's also more simple to write. Using pickles is fairly similar and even has the same syntax, but objects are saved as bytes and not text (so you have to use `'rb'` and `'wb'` modes on files to read and write, respectively).

To do the same thing with numpy array, we can also use [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html):

```
np.save('save', your_numpy_array)
```

And we read it back (with a `npy` extension) with [numpy.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html):

```
your_array = np.load('save.npy')
```

In readability terms, opening the file would be semi-readable (less than JSON, more than pickle)

Comment: First of all thank you for your effort, I imagined that i saved it as a string. I tried json, but I get an error 
"TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable"

Comment: @NoobProgrammer I added an example that would work on numpy array